# Numerous linking errors "undefined reference to `libXX_YY"

Tags: debian, build

I've been trying to compile an open-source C++ project [Typesense](https://github.com/typesense/typesense), which has this list of dependencies:

- Snappy
- zlib
- OpenSSL (>=1.0.2)
- curl
- ICU
- brpc
- braft

Host and target OS is Debian Linux. Compilation is handled via `cmake`->`make` sequence of commands. I was able to install some of dependencies through a package manager (I believe they reside in `/usr/lib` then), the last two I had to compile on my own, I put them in `/usr/local/lib`.

All the dependencies were successfully compiled, and the target project compiled too.

When it comes to linking stage, I get numerous errors like

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-easy.o): in function `global_init':
(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `libssh2_init'

...

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http2.o): in function `on_header':
(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `nghttp2_session_get_stream_user_data'

...

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-socks_gssapi.o): in function `check_gss_err.part.0':
(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `gss_release_buffer'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x77): undefined reference to `gss_display_status'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `gss_release_buffer'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `gss_release_buffer'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0xef): undefined reference to `gss_display_status'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x112): undefined reference to `gss_release_buffer'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x17e): undefined reference to `gss_release_buffer'

...

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-curl_rtmp.o): in function `rtmp_connect':
(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `RTMP_Connect1'

...

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-openldap.o): in function `ldap_connecting':
(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `ldap_result'
```

There is at least a hundred of such errors. I'm not at all proficient with Linux and complex building of projects. How do I possibly fix linking errors for libraries that I just downloaded through a package manager?

Comment: Did you update your [LD_PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168340/where-is-ld-library-path-how-do-i-set-the-ld-library-path-env-variable) environment variable?

Comment: @DavidPostill when it's empty, it throws the same errors, when I added paths to the libraries compiled by myself, it still threw the same errors. I'm just not sure what to add in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Isn't `/usr/lib` already considered by `ld` by default?

Comment: You need to have the appropriate path in the `ld -L` option at build time.